# conda version of pandas mismatch

Tags: python, pandas, anaconda

I use the Anaconda suite for python. I do

`import pandas as pd`

and then

```
pd.show_versions()
```

it shows

> pandas: 0.17.1

but if I do

```
!conda list
```

it shows

> pandas                    0.18.1

Why are those different ? Why is the imported pandas version less up to date than the one in conda ? Some attributes do not work for me at this stage (like .rolling) which is a great hassle.
I've already tried
   `conda update pandas`
and then restart spyder, but without any luck

Thanks a lot for your help

----EDITS :
`pd.__file__` returns

> Out[16]: 'C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py'

`sys.executable` returns

> 'C:\Anaconda3\python.exe'

I've tried `sys.path` which returns

> Out[15]:  ['',  'C:\Anaconda3\python35.zip',  'C:\Anaconda3\DLLs',
>   'C:\Anaconda3\lib',  'C:\Anaconda3',
>   'c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools-23.0.0-py3.5.egg',
>   'C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages',
>   'C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\Sphinx-1.4.1-py3.5.egg',
>   'C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\win32',
>   'C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\win32\lib',
>   'C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin',
>   'C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\extensions',
>   'C:\Users\jeanbaptiste.lepetit\.ipython',
>   'C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\extensions',
>   'C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\extensions']

`pd.__version__` returns

> '0.17.1'

It's quite confusing

----------EDIT 2 ----------------
Ok I figures packages where at two places

> C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas
>   and
>   C:\Anaconda3\pkgs\pandas-0.18.1-np110py35_0\Lib\site-packages\pandas

I manually deleted the first one to see what would happen. then try to import the package : `import pandas as pd` but it couldn't find it. Trying `conda install pandas` returns

> All requested packages already installed.
>   packages in environment at C:\Anaconda3:
>   pandas                    0.18.1              np110py35_0

So I guess it is in this folder that all the `conda` command go, but `import` doesn't work. I've tried to add `C:\Anaconda3\pkgs' to the PATH, but with no luck.

Any idea ?

Comment: Do you try to restart `spyder`after update `pandas` version ?

Comment: Try `pd.__file__` to see where the library is loaded from.

Comment: It looks like you have multiple python instances on your OS, and anaconda is not default one used.  You may need to configure your OS to use anaconda by default.

Comment: Depends on which OS you're using. If you search google for something like  "add anaconda to path os_name" it should give your better instructions than what I can provide.  You may also need to remove the existing python version from the path.

Comment: Also, using the interpreter that has the old version of pandas, try running `import sys` and check the output of `sys.executable` to see if it points to the anaconda directory, or some other python executable.

Comment: use `imp` module like `from imp import find_module` then `find_module('pandas')` to know which path or you can load the pandas version you want using `imp.load_module(name, file, pathname, description)`.

Comment: Have made a second edit to the question, seems like I have packages at two places in the Anaconda3 subfolders... why it is the case I don't know ? Perhaps using both `conda` and `pip` commands ? Still it's not working right now

Answer (score 4):

Eventually, fiddling with all the above answers and looking at other stackoverflow questions, I figured that 'pip-installed-packages' would not go in the same directory as 'conda-installed-packages'. Typically, pip-instlled go to C:\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages while conda-installed go to C:\Anaconda3\pkgs.

I removed manually the 'pandas' folder from C:\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages, but for some reason, Python was unable to find the remaining conda-installed pandas package even after I added 'C:\Anaconda3\pkgs' to the PATH

Eventually I went for an ad-hoc hardcode to the PATH an added 'C:\Anaconda3\pkgs\pandas-0.18.1-np110py35_0\Lib\site-packages' to the PATH and it worked (for this package at least)

What I don't explain to myself is how python manages to find other conda-installed packages (packages for which there is no "specific" path hardcoded as I've done for pandas.

Comment: This is a great question, and I am having similar problems with scikit-learn (conda list shows 0.19.0, but python __version__ shows 0.20.1). I suppose this is why Anaconda has a warning about adding the python install to %PATH%...

Comment: I've also had this exact problem with Seaborn 0.9 (conda) and Seaborn 0.7.1 (pip)

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem. I discovered that pandas was not only installed in the two folders indicated by JB Lepetit, but also in "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages". It was here where the version of pandas was being taken. The problem was solved by simply erasing the pandas folder from here. Hope this helps.